# Why doesn't β-elimination occur in Cr(CMe3)4?

Tags: organometallic-compounds, organic-reduction

By $\beta$-elimination, I am refering to the reaction where a M-C-C-H structure reduces to ($\eta^2$-alkene)-M-H.

My lecture notes claim that $\ce{Cr(CMe3)4}$ is stable and does not incur such elimination reactions due to "geometric constraints", but I am having trouble understanding why that is.

Whether the molecule is tetrahedral or square planar, it feels like there should be enough room for hydrogen to bond to the metal.

As the molecule is unsaturated, the metal should be able to provide an empty orbital to accept the hydrogen's electron pair.

It certainly doesn't help that I can't search for this molecule, either as "tetra-t-butyl chromium", "tetra-tert-butyl chromium", "tetrakis-t-butyl chromium" or other variations of these.

Comment: There should **not** be enough room. That's the point. Too little space for it to be planar, too. It's tetrahedral and Cr surrounded by ligands almost completely. It's not really an issue about this complex, you were already told the reason, but some misunderstanding how bulky ligands can be.

Comment: @Mithoron Thanks a lot! You are right; I am just beginning to study organic chemistry and have little intuition on the bulkiness of ligands.

Comment: A paper on obtaining the compound can be found at https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-328X(00)81814-8 . It claims half-life of 4.5 min at 70 C in heptane. It offers minimal discussion on the fact, but the intro contains some links that might be useful

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/004060909290719R